# Using angled border on Bootstrap Navbar and expanding this to collapsing Navbar dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I just have a quick question regarding Bootstrap 4.0. I am trying to make a navbar that has a angled look to it at the bottom. and I have got that to work using multiple methods mainly using the ::after Pseudo-elements as you can see here: [Navbar normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xkni4.png). Now this is all fine and good but I came across something that bothers me, when I reduce the window size, and I click the navbar hamburger to expand it, this angled look is behind the dropdown: [Navbar in mobile mode hidden by dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cuKW.png). I basically want to add the angled detail to the drop down box, so that it looks similar to the normal navbar.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Here is my CSS aswell

```
.navbar:after{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
border-left: 100vw solid #343a40;
top: 56px;
left: 0;
z-index: -1;}
```

I have been able to attach it to the dropdown box, by adding the same thing to the div that is being toggled when the hamburger is pressed. But since I am using Pseudo elements the border only appears with some delay after the animation takes place. Not really what I want; so my question is basically is there a way to attach it so this delay doesnt happen? maybe I am approaching this completely wrong could use some help here.